# Fetch data from mysql database

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

How to pass array into where, if this array has dynamic values ?

```
foreach($value as  $v)
{
        echo $v->acc_pkey." ";
        $account = ledger::where('ledger_group', '=', 18)->orwhere('ledger_group', '=', $v->acc_pkey)->get();
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: Can you please provide some more info.?

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that question @NileshKhisadiya?

Comment: @NileshKhisadiya, that's not even related, it's for `Laravel` not plain `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can use `whereIn()` instead. So you can have:

```
$values = $value->pluck('acc_pkey')->toArray();
$account = ledger::whereIn('ledger_group', $values)->get();
```

Or could it be:

```
$account = ledger::where('ledger_group', '=', 18)
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($values) {
        $query->whereIn('ledger_group', $values);
    })->get();
```

.....

I don't know what you really have in Mind, but I guess this should suffice except this solution is against your `orWhere()` in the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have to put **'='** in a where,

```
 $whereData = [
      'ledger_group' => $v->acc_pkey,
    ];
    foreach($value as  $v) {
        echo $v->acc_pkey." ";

        $account = ledger::where('ledger_group',18)
                         ->orwhere($whereData)
                         ->get();
    }
```